# send parameters from java to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, war

I would like to send parameters from a java file that does a specific job to index.jsp file. How to achieve it? Basically my application gets data from wsdl link and java file processes it. And I want to pass the output of java file to jsp.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can save them in the request object and access them from the JSP using EL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
request.setAttribute("value",valueFromWSDL);
```

This can be set in the java.

In the index.jsp you can use

```
request.getAttribut("value");
```

to obtain the value

Comment: in jsp just ${value.memberSomethingIfneeded}